# Is there a synopsis about how to do certain things with different scm tools?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial

I'm quite familiar with Subversion, and I use Mercurial and Git as well.
Mercurial looks like a friendly tool to me, as it's commandline interface is easy to use for Subversion users; but Git doesn't.

Is there a comparison sheet somewhere, which e.g. allows to see at a glance how to revert local changes for single files, or all, with `svn`, `hg` and `git` commands?

Comment: if you feel one of the answers answers your question, please mark that one as accepted so this question can be 'closed'

Comment: Since there is none for now which includes `svn` (which is the one I'm familiar with), sadly I can't ...

Answer (score 1):

I know of this page, which gives a translation between hg and git:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GitConcepts

Comment: Thanks - the [Command equivalence table](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GitConcepts#Command_equivalence_table) looks like something I'd like to have - but including `svn` ...

Answer (score 1):

See the table under [this wikipedia page on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software#Basic_commands).

It lists svn. mercurial, git and many more. More specific information about commands can of course be found in the docs on their websites, but at least this shows what similar commands look like in different SCMs.

Comment: Yes, this certainly helps. Collecting information about *so many* tools makes it impossible to be more verbose, of course.

Comment: Yep very true, thats why I pointed to the individual docs ;-)